Dynamically selection of codebehind class
Let's assume we have following simple webform page with single button:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.Pages.Tr.WebForm1" %>

    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" />

And this code-behind:
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*some behavior*/
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         /*some behavior*/
    }
}

Now, let's assume we have some special customer, who requires some additional special actions when clicking the button.
I would like to achieve it by writing an inherited class - something like:
public class SpecialWebForm : WebForm1
{
    override void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);
        /*special behavior*/
    }
}

Is it possible to dynamically select implementation of code-behind class? To make somewhere something like:
if (IsSpecial(CurrentClient))
{
    WebForm1.CodeBehind = new SpecialWebForm();
}

or something like that?

Page markup is not loaded and then the class is created. It works the other way around. The markup is "used" to create the page class. Take a look at a designer.cs file to see how this works. This suggests then to move all your business code in that page behind out to some business class object, and scope the business object to the page class. Then say using factory pattern create an instance of the different class to be used based on "some special customer". Nothing says all your code behind has to be in that page, and you should move as much code logic out from code behind anyway.

There probably not going to be that much code behind anyway, and if there is then move it out to some separate class, and thus you have more flexible code. But, no, it not practical or likely even possible to swap out the page class to be used. That page is only giving you some UI anyway, and having large amounts of code behind always been a bad idea, and webforms unfortunately encourages one to lump lots of code behind  but it still not a great idea. And it would be VERY difficult to manage 2 classes, since any and all events etc. would have to 100% match up anyway.

I was thinking about the Model-View-Presenter (MVP) pattern and how it can be adapted to fit your case. Even though the Presenter is the component that "presents" the UI to the user it's also the component that accepts user commands, which matches your requirement. After all, clicking the button(s) probably results in an updated Model (data) presented by the View (WebForm), I assume.
Consider the following example where Message is a property used to demonstrate the execution of different behaviors between two Web Forms, WebForm1 and SpecialWebForm, both having the same markup:
Markup of WebForm1 and SpecialWebForm
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Click Me" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />

In code-behind, both web forms implement common interface IWebForm and delegate behavior implementation and model updating to the proper instance (SimpleWebFormPresenter or SpecialWebFormPresenter) of IWebFormPresenter:
public interface IWebForm
{
    string Message { set; }
}

public interface IWebFormPresenter
{
    void Handle();
}

WebForm1.aspx.cs
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page, IWebForm
{
    private IWebFormPresenter presenter;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.presenter = new SimpleWebFormPresenter(this);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.presenter.Handle();
    }

    public string Message
    {
        set
        {
            Label1.Text = value;
        }
    }
}

SpecialWebForm.aspx.cs
public partial class SpecialWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page, IWebForm
{
    private IWebFormPresenter presenter;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.presenter = new SpecialWebFormPresenter(this);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.presenter.Handle();
    }

    public string Message
    {
        set
        {
            Label1.Text = value;
        }
    }
}

SimpleWebFormPresenter
public class SimpleWebFormPresenter : IWebFormPresenter
{
    private IWebForm webForm;

    public SimpleWebFormPresenter(IWebForm webForm)
    {
        this.webForm = webForm;
    }

    public void Handle()
    {
        webForm.Message = "Simple behavior";
    }
}

SpecialWebFormPresenter
public class SpecialWebFormPresenter : IWebFormPresenter
{
    private IWebForm webForm;

    public SpecialWebFormPresenter(IWebForm webForm)
    {
        this.webForm = webForm; 
    }

    public void Handle()
    {
        webForm.Message = "Special behavior";
    }
}

As a result, clicking the WebForm1 button will update Label1 with "Simple behavior" whereas clicking the SpecialWebForm button will update Label1 with "Special behavior".
Hope it helps.
